# File Access error

Tags: vb6

When I am trying to open a file in to TX Text control through VB 6 code, It states that the "File Cannot Be Opened" !!!
 What may possibly go wrong here?

Comment: We need more details. What kind of file is it? Can you open it in another application? What code are you using to open the file? Where is the file located? Do you have administrative rights? Etc. See here for tips on writing a good question: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @@ Gray:: well my VB 6 Application uses a simple TX Text control Load() function to open this woprd file (.doc).The file resides in the same application path.I created the file just few mins ago!!!

Comment: What is a TX Text control? Is it a third party control? Can you tell us the name of the company who make it, or provide a link to some online documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the file is most likely locked by another process.

Try using the [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) tool to find out which process has it locked.

Comment: Well, I cannot download any external software. Is there any other way out?

Comment: @Rajdeep: Try creating a very basic app yourself that just opens that file in read-write mode using normal IO. If your app fails to do so, then it's probably a problem with the file (locked, or permissions etc) but if your app manages to open it, then it's probably a problem with the way the text control opens it.